# Regex cookie value

Tags: regex, arr

I need to extract cookie value and use it in outbound rewrite rule as a back reference. And if Set-Cookie header does not contain this cookie, back reference should be empty.

So I created condition and stuck at creating proper regex. **Regex should match every input**. Back reference value for cookie named `locale` for strings

- `somecookie=somevalue;locale=en-US;expires=-1`
- `locale=en-US`
- `somecookie=somevalue;locale=en-US`
- `locale=en-US;expires=-1`

should be `en-US`. For strings

- `somecookie=somevalue;local=en-US;expires=-1`
- `;expires=-1`
- ''
  back reference value should be ``.

Any ideas for such a regex?

Comment: In which tool/language are you doing this? Can you show the code you attempted?

Comment: It's Application Request Routing in IIS. There is no code, just web application config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?=.*?locale)locale=(.*?);.*$|(?!.*?locale).*=().*$
```

You can use this.

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/16)

Comment: I've added some inputs for testing. There is no `somecookie` in real input, I've used it for examples

Comment: you variant does not pass second and third test input. I've modified it and it works `(?=.*?locale)locale=([^;]*).*$|(?!.*?locale).*=().*$`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This regex optionally matches the locale value:

```
.*locale=([^;\s]+).*|.+
```

The back reference group 1.

[See live demo](http://rubular.com/r/tOQJFSgWE6) matching correctly with your examples.

This works by using an alternation for a match with locale *or* match anything, knowing that alternation matching is left-to-right, ie the left side is attempted first and if it fails to match only then is the right side attempted.

Comment: Second input does not match, but every input should. And ARR displays an error showing that expression syntax is incorrect. It seems to me that ARR does not support lookbehind

Comment: Will there always be "local", or is the idea that the entire locale value is optional?

Comment: `locale=...` section is optional

Comment: Ok. I have changed the regex a simple pattern that works with all your new examples, capturing the locale if one is present, or blank otherwise.